# Ignore html tags on preg_match

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

Im scrapping a site with following html

```
<a class="name" href="/link" data-hovercard-id="charshere"><span class="highlighted">War</span> World</a> 

<a class="name" href="/link" data-hovercard-id="charshere"> World of <span class="highlighted">fun</span></a> 

<a class="name" href="/link" data-hovercard-id="charshere">Save the<br>world</a> 

<a class="name" href="/link" data-hovercard-id="charshere">world of warcraft</a>
```

using this code i get the value of links

```
preg_match_all('/<a class="name" href=".*?" data-hovercard-id=".*?">(.*)<\/a>/i', $file_string, $titles);
```

but the outcome is

```
<span class="highlighted">War</span> World
 World of <span class="highlighted">fun</span>
Save the<br>world
world of warcraft
```

How do i ignore the html tags inside of it? so that it would look like this

```
 War World
 World of fun
 Save the world
 world of warcraft
```

A DomDocument could be better. Thanks. been trying to use domDocument but I not familiar how to use its xquery.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). Here comes an example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<span class="highlighted">War</span> World
 World of <span class="highlighted">fun</span>
Save the<br>world
world of warcraft
EOF;

echo strip_tags($html);
```

Output:

```
War World
 World of fun
Save theworld
world of warcraft
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the tags after you get the text:

```
<?php
$string = '<span class="highlighted">War</span> World
 World of <span class="highlighted">fun</span>
Save the<br>world
world of warcraft';
$convert = preg_replace('/<.*?>/','', $string);
print $convert;
```

Prints:

```
War World
 World of fun
Save theworld
world of warcraft
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the HTML tags after you've matched your string for the links. For example

```
$str = preg_replace('/<[^<]+>/', '', $html);
```